# How Turn On Linux Network Port Listeners

Tags: postgresql, network

I'm on AlmaLinux 9 where I want to host PostgreSQL for the LAN.

I've poked a hole in the firewall (`firewalld`):

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=postgresql
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port 5432/tcp
```

The port is visible, but it is in a `closed` state:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-11 03:06 EDT
Nmap scan report for server_n.local (192.168.1.23)
Host is up (0.00024s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql
MAC Address: D0:50:99:87:7B:4A (ASRock Incorporation)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds

nc (netcat):
nc: connectx to 192.168.1.23 port 5432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

So I can tweak it open for a short time with `nc`, but that is more of a troubleshooting or scripting tool, rather than a solid way of keeping ports open.

How can I make sure PostgreSQL is alive and properly listening?

Comment: What does visible but in a closed state mean?  You are apparently using nmap, but didn't show the command you gave it.

Comment: @jjanes `nmap -sS -p 5400-6500 server_n.local` would return `5432/tcp closed  postgresql`, so `nmap` could see that port responding, but it was `closed`.

Comment: I think closed and Connection refused mean the same thing here, Postgresql is not running, or at least not listening for remote connections on the default port.  You don't describe either installing or configuring or starting PostgreSQL, so maybe it shouldn't be a surprise that it is not running.

Comment: I'm successfully getting in with my workstation.  This is truly odd.  Those connections now show `postgresql` as `open`.  I'm paying close attention this week to that issue.